# Basic text mining and ETL for BigQuery with Python

Tags: python, etl, text-mining

As an exercise I need to perform text mining with Python on the given data set:  https://www.kaggle.com/bigquery/patentsview

Expected results are:
*- 3 most popular nouns in claim.text associated to each of the cpc_subsection.title category

- the most associated noun in claim.text to each of the 3 highest nouns. Ie. Most associated noun -> Most popular noun -> Title category.*

I've managed to connect to that data set, I am able to view its content.
My general idea is that I would need to create a list for every 'text' index to compare it later with every index of 'title' strings. Then a loop with a counter for every 'title' match. Highest 3 results listed at the end.

However, after several hours of overcoming errors on every possible step to this point, I can not figure out how the code should look like to perform the task.

Edit4:
**Alright, I've made a code which provides with all matches at the end but not divided to particular nouns - just total matches.**

```
import bq_helper
import collections
from pandas import DataFrame
from bq_helper import BigQueryHelper
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "C:/Users/Jamba/BigQuery-45ba6cef6c37.json"
patentsview = bq_helper.BigQueryHelper(active_project="patents-public-data", dataset_name="patentsview")
bq_assistant = BigQueryHelper("patents-public-data", "patentsview")
tab = bq_assistant.head("cpc_subsection", num_rows=137)
tab2 = bq_assistant.head("claim", num_rows=10)

df = DataFrame(tab, columns=['title'])
title_list = df.values.tolist()

df2 = DataFrame(tab2, columns=['text'])
text_list = df2.values.tolist()

flat_list = []
for x in title_list:
    for noun in x:
        flat_list.append(noun)

text_in_cpc = []
for strings in flat_list:
    text_in_cpc = text_in_cpc + strings.split(';')

words_in_cpc = []
for strings in text_in_cpc:
    words_in_cpc = words_in_cpc + strings.split()

nouns_in_cpc = [s for s in words_in_cpc if s != 'OR' and s != 'OF' and s != 'TO' and s != 'IN' and s != 'A'
                and s != 'AND' and s != 'NOT' and s != 'FOR' and s != 'THAN' and s != 'THE' and s != 'FROM'
                and s != 'WITH' and s != 'BY' and s != 'AN' and s != 'ON' and s != 'THEIR' and s != 'VARIOUS']
print(nouns_in_cpc)

flat_list2 = []
for descriptions in text_list:
    for text in descriptions:
        flat_list2.append(text)

text_in_claim = []
for strings in flat_list2:
    text_in_claim = text_in_claim+strings.split()
print(text_in_claim)

TT1 = 0 #TOTAL TRUES
TF1 = 0 #TOTAL FALSES
for title in nouns_in_cpc:
    comparison = title.rstrip('.  ').lstrip().lower()
    for word in text_in_claim:
        if word.rstrip('.  ').rstrip(',  ').lstrip().lower() == comparison:
            TT1 = TT1+1
            print("comparing %s with %s: %s" % (word.rstrip('.  ').rstrip(',  ').lstrip().lower(), comparison,
                                                word.rstrip('.  ').rstrip(',  ').lstrip().lower() == comparison))
        else:
            TF1 = TF1+1
print(f'Falses: {TF1}')
print(f'Trues: {TT1}')
```

**EDIT5: It's finished for the first point. I will share the code when I can.**

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: Hi. At the moment I am clueless what and how to code next. I am trying with a "counter" from here now: https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html
However most basic coding seems not to work with my environment as I keep getting "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'."

Comment: Oh, and the part I am struggling with: obtaining "3 most popular nouns in claim.text associated to each of the cpc_subsection.title category"

Comment: _However most basic coding seems not to work with my environment as I keep getting "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'."_ Where are you getting that error? Can you share the entire thing?

Comment: @AMC edited the post for up-to-date comments and code

Comment: What leads to the _"SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'."_ ?